# How can I avoid displacements in exported JPEGS from QGIS 2.2?

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I observed a small but annoying problem for a long time now. I have to design maps/plans of survey areas for work including maps where a satellite image is printed under a vector-layer showing the outlines of the single survey fields. For the satellite images I use the build in Google Satellite layer from the OpenLayers plugin.

In QGIS everything looks OK, but when I export a JPEG or PDF-File from QGIS there is often a significant displacement of the Satellite Layer.

I tried to solve this by setting different Spatial reference systems or using Bing Satellite instead of Google, but it seems to have nothing to do with that. I found out, that it sometimes helps to set the plan to another scale before exporting. But this is often to big or doesn't help.

Anyone ever had this problem and/or know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that's gone back to QGIS version 1.8 or so - still unfixed, unfortunately.  This source (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827) has more info on what's been done so far to try and deal with it.